# getChoices not getting choices

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I got a quick question concerning a small Script I am trying to write within the google Apps Script editor.

I created a small google forms document with some basic checkBoxItem-questions with multiple choices. Now I am trying to read the questions and the choices (not the answers). All I am getting with the script below are "Item,Item,Item..." and "Choice,Choice,Choice...".

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  var ques = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < ques.length; i++){  
  var sques = ques[i].getTitle();
  var choices = ques[i].asCheckboxItem().getChoices();
 Logger.log("All Questions: "+ques+", specific Question: "+sques+", Possible answers to Question "+i+": "+choices+"");
}}
```

The documentation says that "getChoices" "Gets all choices for an item.". In my case it only gives the right amount of "Choice" (i.e. Choice,Choice for 2 possible choices) but not the text.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getChoices()` [returns an *array* of the choices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#getChoices()) for the item. You need to iterate in another loop. You can push the titles into another array (below) or write each choice out.

```js
function test() {
  var choicesArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var formUrl = ss.getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  var ques = form.getItems();

  for (var i = 0; i < ques.length; i++){  
    var sques = ques[i].getTitle();
    var choices = ques[i].asCheckboxItem().getChoices(); // an array of choices

    choices.forEach(function(a) {
      choicesArray.push(a.getValue()); // push each choice value into a new array
    });

    Logger.log("All Questions: "+ques+", specific Question: "+sques+", 
    Possible answers to Question "+i+": "+choicesArray+"");
  }
}
```